# Intel i7-870 running on Mini-ITX-PC adviseable?

Tags: intel-core-i7, mini-itx

I need the Intel i7-870 for a machine, mainly used for programming Java, Flash CS5, etc.

I would love to make a small form factor and silent machine but wonder if it is possible and adviseable.

These are my 2 favourites so far:

- [Shuttle SH67H3](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004UC4HCG)
- [Lian Li Case](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811112227&Tpk=lian%20li%20q07) , [Arctic Freezer 13](http://www.amazon.de/Arctic-Freezer-K%C3%BChler-Sockel-1366/dp/B0048F64DU/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top) , [Be quiet SFX 350](http://www.amazon.de/quiet-350W-Power-PC-Netzteil-Watt/dp/B002OCYAUS/ref=sr_1_1?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1330978232&sr=1-1) , some SSD Harddisk and decent RAM
  i would chose the H67 Motherboard since i hope the intern graphic is sufficient for me.

I target a CPU temp at 30 Grad degrees Celsius on Windows 7 idle. No overclocking needed.

Would you think shuttle can handle this or would you build your own? Is Mini-ITX possible to build a low-temperature system with i7?
Do you already have an i7 running on a Mini-ITX. How about temperature?

Thanks for any advise guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. its NOT advisable regarding the fact that the cpu in most nowadays mini-cases has to run on significant higher temperatures compared to a midi-sized computer. i had it running on a shuttle mini (USD 390 for case, psu, mobo) with additional high-end fans. the cpu was at 40 Degrees C at idle compared to 29 at a midi tower with room for a high-tower Cooler.

If you are like me and rely on the computer (for work, gaming addiction or whatever) it wouldn't be accurate to sacrifice your cpu's lifespan just for a smaller form factor.